# how to disable the week # hover on angular-bootstrap-calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I am using [angular-bootstrap-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) but a do not want that hover that indicates the number on the left. 
Is there a way to disable it ?
Tried using the config parameter calendarConfig.i18nStrings.weekNumber with no effect.
Thanks a lot "!

calendarConfig.i18nStrings.weekNumber = null;

Answer (score 4):

You can put

```
#cal-week-box {
    display: none;
}
```

in your css for an easy fix, it doesn't look like you can disable it with code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like `.cal-week-box-cell` was the display to remove   in version that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for the latest version:

```
.cal-week-box-cell { 
       display: none; 
}
```

how you can read [here](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar/issues/261)